# Convert strings (having different formats) to datetime in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a following dataframe:

```
df= {'DateTime': {0: '2017-08-02T00:00:00Z', 1: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.050Z', 2: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.100Z', 3: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.150Z', 4: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.200Z', 5: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.250Z', 6: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.300Z', 7: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.350Z', 8: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.400Z', 9: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.450Z', 10: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.500Z', 11: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.550Z', 12: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.600Z', 13: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.650Z', 14: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.700Z', 15: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.750Z', 16: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.800Z', 17: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.850Z', 18: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.900Z', 19: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.950Z', 20: '2017-08-02T00:00:01Z'}}
```

I want to convert column "DateTime" to `datetime` format but the problem is that strings are of different patterns. E.g., first row is in the format `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"` but rows 2-19 are in the format of `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"` and again row 20th is in the format `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"`. How this kind of column can be converted to datetime?

Comment: Do you really need to specify the formats? `df.DateTime.apply(pd.to_datetime)` without any format set seems to work just fine...

Comment: Correct! But output is like 2017-08-02 00:00:00+00:00, 2017-08-02 00:00:00.050000+00:00, ...... Isn't there any problem having +00:00?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with datetime objects, but I don't think it's an issue, after converting to datetime you can get rid of the timezone with `df.DateTime.dt.tz_localize(None)`.

Comment: @fsimonjetz you should have added this as an answer ;-) The accepted one over-complicates things imho. +00:00 means UTC since you have a Z in your input (format is ISO 8601 btw., Z for Zulu time), so this is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe...

**Simply:**

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': {0: '2017-08-02T00:00:00Z', 1: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.050Z', 2: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.100Z', 3: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.150Z', 4: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.200Z', 5: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.250Z', 6: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.300Z', 7: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.350Z', 8: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.400Z', 9: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.450Z', 10: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.500Z', 11: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.550Z', 12: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.600Z', 13: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.650Z', 14: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.700Z', 15: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.750Z', 16: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.800Z', 17: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.850Z', 18: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.900Z', 19: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.950Z', 20: '2017-08-02T00:00:01Z'}})
    
    df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']).dt.tz_localize(None)
```

**Or:**

```
    import pandas as pd
    from dateutil.parser import parse
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': {0: '2017-08-02T00:00:00Z', 1: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.050Z', 2: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.100Z', 3: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.150Z', 4: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.200Z', 5: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.250Z', 6: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.300Z', 7: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.350Z', 8: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.400Z', 9: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.450Z', 10: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.500Z', 11: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.550Z', 12: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.600Z', 13: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.650Z', 14: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.700Z', 15: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.750Z', 16: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.800Z', 17: '2017-08 02T00:00:00.850Z', 18: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.900Z', 19: '2017-08-02T00:00:00.950Z', 20: '2017-08-02T00:00:01Z'}})
    
    df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].apply(lambda x: parse(x))
    df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

**Or:**

```
import pandas as pd
import dateparser

df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].apply(lambda x: dateparser.parse(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

**Output:**

```
    DateTime
0   2017-08-02 00:00:00.000000
1   2017-08-02 00:00:00.050000
2   2017-08-02 00:00:00.100000
3   2017-08-02 00:00:00.150000
4   2017-08-02 00:00:00.200000
5   2017-08-02 00:00:00.250000
6   2017-08-02 00:00:00.300000
7   2017-08-02 00:00:00.350000
8   2017-08-02 00:00:00.400000
9   2017-08-02 00:00:00.450000
10  2017-08-02 00:00:00.500000
11  2017-08-02 00:00:00.550000
12  2017-08-02 00:00:00.600000
13  2017-08-02 00:00:00.650000
14  2017-08-02 00:00:00.700000
15  2017-08-02 00:00:00.750000
16  2017-08-02 00:00:00.800000
17  2017-08-02 00:00:00.850000
18  2017-08-02 00:00:00.900000
19  2017-08-02 00:00:00.950000
20  2017-08-02 00:00:01.000000
```

Comment: I think this is overcomplicated. A simple `df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])` does the trick. If you want no time zone specified, localize to None (`.dt.tz_localize(None)`).

Comment: Np.  Added the option to make its available.

Comment: thanks for updating, I'd put that as the first option ^^ btw. I didn't downvote.

Comment: Done.  Voting is 50/50 at the moment.  A real Marmite answer.

Answer (score 1):

One option is try to convert for each format separately and then merge the results:

```
formats = ["%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ", "%Y-%m %dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"]
parsed_dt = pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime, format=formats[0], errors='coerce')
for format in formats[1:]:
    parsed_dt = parsed_dt.fillna(pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime, format=format, errors='coerce'))

parsed_dt
0    2017-08-02 00:00:00.000
1    2017-08-02 00:00:00.050
2    2017-08-02 00:00:00.100
3    2017-08-02 00:00:00.150
4    2017-08-02 00:00:00.200
5    2017-08-02 00:00:00.250
6    2017-08-02 00:00:00.300
7    2017-08-02 00:00:00.350
8    2017-08-02 00:00:00.400
9    2017-08-02 00:00:00.450
10   2017-08-02 00:00:00.500
11   2017-08-02 00:00:00.550
12   2017-08-02 00:00:00.600
13   2017-08-02 00:00:00.650
14   2017-08-02 00:00:00.700
15   2017-08-02 00:00:00.750
16   2017-08-02 00:00:00.800
17   2017-08-02 00:00:00.850
18   2017-08-02 00:00:00.900
19   2017-08-02 00:00:00.950
20   2017-08-02 00:00:01.000
Name: DateTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```